# What is the wheel user group for?

Tags: macos, unix

The output of `groups` after `sudo bash` lists the following groups:

```
wheel daemon kmem sys tty operator procview procmod everyone staff certusers localaccounts admin com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 _appstore _lpadmin _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
```

What is the `wheel` user group for and why is it called `wheel`?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29 and also: http://superuser.com/questions/191955/what-is-the-wheel-user-in-os-x

Comment: thanks. I thought it would be useful to have the answer here too.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/191955/what-is-the-wheel-user-in-os-x) by [Rich Homolka](https://superuser.com/users/8804/rich-homolka):

> Mac OS X has roots in BSD UNIX, a.k.a. the UNIX that came out of [UC
>   Berkeley](http://berkeley.edu/).  They had a group of trusted people
>   that could become superuser by using the `su` command.  So they coded
>   their UNIX to only allow people in this specific group to become
>   superuser using `su`.  They chose the groupname 'wheel', supposedly
>   reference to other systems that had WHEEL, possibly a reference to
>   being a '[big
>   wheel](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/big-wheel)'
>
> It's less important now that you have the GUI authorization popups and
>   sudo.  You can use sudo without being in wheel group I believe.

Comment: When in grad school I heard the expression:  "Only 2 things ever came out of Berkeley, BSD, and LSD. That was not a coincidence".  lol

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29):

Modern Unix systems use user groups to control access privileges. The wheel group is a special user group used on some Unix systems to control access to the su command, which allows a user to masquerade as another user (usually the super user).

In computing, the term wheel refers to a user account with a wheel bit, a system setting that provides additional special system privileges that empower a user to execute restricted commands that ordinary user accounts cannot access.The term is derived from the slang phrase big wheel, referring to a person with great power or influence.

Comment: This is mostly irrelevant on OS X, since most of the functions traditionally controlled by wheel membership have been replaced by things that use the admin group instead (e.g. `sudo` is generally used instead of `su`, and `sudo` is configured to allow members of admin to use it).